# Spring Batch Step Failure

Tags: spring-batch

In case of step failure in a multi-step batch , the step fail message is shown on console.
Also the `BATCH_STATUS` is `COMPLETED` and `EXIT_STATUS` is `FAILED.`

Q.1 How to change the `EXIT_STATUS` to `COMPLETED`?

Q.2 Is it anyway possible not to show failure message in console

Sample Code

```
 <job id="someJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
     restartable="true" parent="baseJob">
    <step id="aStep">
        <job ref="aJob" />
        <next on="*" to="bStep"/>
    </step>
    <step id="bStep" parent="aStep" next="cStep">
        <job ref="bJob"/>
    </step>
    <step id="cStep" parent="bStep">
        <job ref="cJob"/>
    </step>
</job>

 <job id="aJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
         restartable="true" parent="baseJob">
    <step id="aJobStep">
        <tasklet ref="aJobTasklet" />
    </step>
</job>

<job id="bJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
         restartable="true" parent="baseJob">
    <step id="bJobStep">
        <tasklet ref="bJobTasklet" />
    </step>
</job>

<job id="cJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
         restartable="true" parent="baseJob">
    <step id="cJobStep">
        <tasklet ref="cJobTasklet" />
    </step>
</job>
```

if Step `aStep` fails for job `someJob` (`aStep` has thrown some `SQLException`).
Then `someJob` is continued to execute. But after successful completion of `cStep`, `BATCH_STATUS` for `someJob` is `COMPLETED` but `EXIT_STATUS` = `FAILED`.
Also `BATCH_STATUS` and `EXIT_STATUS` of other steps are as follows.

```
Step Name BATCH_STATUS  EXIT_STATUS
aStep     FAILED        FAILED
bStep     COMPLETED     COMPLETED
cStep     COMPLETED     COMPLETED
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to ignore the error happening in step?  I think you can do so by using flow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two statuses in Spring Batch.  The first is the `BatchStatus`.  This status consists of a set of pre-defined values that are used by the framework to indicate the state of things.  The other is the `ExitStatus`.  The `ExitStatus` provides the ability for a developer to provide use case specific status messages.

In the execution of a job, there is no way Spring Batch allows you to override the `BatchStatus`.  This is by design.  However, the `ExitStatus` is allowed to be set in a number of places (typically listeners like the `StepExecutionListener` and the `JobExecutionListener`) so that the results from the framework can be interpreted to meet your use case.

If you want to indicate success when the `ExitStatus` typically says that the job or step has failed, you would implement the appropriate listener and set the `ExitStatus` accordingly.

Comment: Returning ExitStatus.COMPLETED from afterStep of StepListener of "aStep" is not working

Comment: Still The Batch Status is COMPLETED and Exit Status is FAILED

Comment: @Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
  
//Step Listener are called in every step of multi step batch
//If condition to clear exception list at only desired step
 if (StringUtils.equals(stepExecution.getStepName(),
    "aStep")) {
   stepExecution.getFailureExceptions().clear();
   stepExecution.getJobExecution().getAllFailureExceptions().clear();
   stepExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.COMPLETED);
   return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
  }
  return null;
 }
 
Now the Batch Status = COMPLETED and Exit Status = COMPLETED even if "aStep" fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to Spring Batch's document on the page about configuring the job (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html , section 5.3.3, you should be able to see the use of `<end>`

It can be done by

```
<job ....>
    <step id="step1"...>
        ....
        <end on="FAILED" />
        <next on="*" to="step2" />
    </step>
    <step id="step2" ....>
        ....
    </step>
</job>
```

By doing so, when step1 failed, the job will end with `COMPLETED` Batch and Exit status.

Comment: If the step1 fails step2 is not getting executed because of <end> element

Comment: Will putting an `<end on="*" />`  in your `cStep` help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below code in the xml:

If want to fail the job upon step failure -- <batch:end exit-code="FAILED" on="FAILED" />
If want to complete the job upon step failure -- <batch:end exit-code="COMPLETED" on="FAILED" />

Include exception handling like below if you want to print a message in logs upon step failure:

```
            <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                <batch:include class="java.lang.Exception" />
            </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener>
                    <bean  class="java.lang.Exception" scope = "step">
                    </bean>
                </batch:listener>
            </batch:listeners>
```